# How to read firestore data in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am new to react native and particullary firebase. I've been watching tutorial about using firebase with react native and i read the react native firebase documentation but i am stuck. I have data in my firestore data base, in my collection called `user` but I am not able to read, to get the data from it. Here is my firestore database :  [image: Here is my firestore database]

and here is how I tried to get the data in my component :

```
const Profile = ({navigation, ...props}) => {



    async function getUserData () {
        const userCollection = await await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()
        return userCollection
    }
    console.log('' + getUserData())
```

this return me that : `[object Object]`

I also tried this, (it was how it was done in the instagram clone tutorial of Adrian Twarog) :

```
const Profile = ({navigation, ...props}) => {

  function getUserDataFirstTry() {
        firebase.firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then((snapchot) => {
            if(snapchot.exists){
                console.log('' +  snapchot.data())
            } else {
                console.log('merde ca marche pas')
            }
        })
    }

    console.log('' + getUserDataFirstTry())
```

But I get the same result in my console : `[object Object]`

I tried to put my function in a useEffect hook but this changes nothing.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong ? (if possible in the second example because it's realtime changes). Thanks.

Comment: `console.log('' +  snapchot.data())` If you concatenate an object to a string, that object is going to be turned into the string `[object Object]`. Try logging just `console.log(snapchot.data())`, or if you want to keep the parrot, do: `console.log('', snapchot.data())`

Comment: omg thank you, I didn't know that javascript was turning that to a string and I was thinking the problem comes from how I get the data. Sometimes the answear is more obvions than we think, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nicholas commented, since you're concatenating `snapchot.data()` to a string, you get the string representation of that object, which is pretty useless.

To log a specific field from the data:

```
console.log('' +  snapchot.data().userName)
```

To log all fields from the data in a more useful format:

```
console.log('' +  JSON.stringify(snapchot.data()))
```

Note: the proper spelling is `snapshot` (not `snapchot`), but I kept your original spelling here for ease of copy/paste.